# Postgres composite / user defined types in Apache NiFi

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I have successfully worked with postgres enum in Apache NiFi 1.24 but I can't read or write columns defined as composite types.

I have used standard jdbc postgres driver and also pgjdbc-ng driver but it did not help. I also tried to define my composite type as an avro record inside my row record but I always get the error :

```
Unable to execute SQL select query SELECT * FROM refugit.payments due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Error during database query or conversion of records.
- Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema: Unknown SQL type 2002 / audit (table: payments, column: audit) cannot be converted to Avro type: {}
```

My audit column is defined as follows :

```
CREATE TYPE refugit.audit AS (
version integer,
user_id uuid,
versiondate timestamptz,
userip inet
);
```

Should I :

- move to NiFi 2.0.0 ?
- write a custom DBCPConnectionPool to define type mapping ?

Any suggestion appreciated !